# Custom UIView and crashing on accessing properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

So I have a subclassed `UIView`:

```
.h
@interface HistogramGraphPanel : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *graphView;

-(id)initWithDataset:(Dataset *)dataset;

@end

.m
-(id)initWithDataset:(Dataset *)dataset {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.dataset = dataset;

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;

        UIView *contentView = [UIView new];
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
        contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        contentView.tag = 6;
        self.contentView = contentView;

        UIView *headerView = [UIView new];
        headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
        headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.headerView = headerView;

        [headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[headerView(60)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerView)]];

        [contentView addSubview:headerView];

        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[headerView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerView)]];
        [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[headerView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerView)]];

        UILabel *headerLabel = [UILabel new];
        headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:HELVETICA_FONT_STYLE_BOLD size:24];
        headerLabel.text = @"Analysis Histogram";
        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

        [headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[headerLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerLabel)]];
        [headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[headerLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(headerLabel)]];

        [self createGraphView];

        self = (HistogramGraphPanel *)contentView;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Creating and using the `UIView` subclass:

```
HistogramGraphPanel *graphPanel = [[HistogramGraphPanel alloc] initWithDataset:dataset];

[self.view addSubview:graphPanel];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[panel]-[graphPanel]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(graphPanel, panel)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(49)-[graphPanel]-(228)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(panel, graphPanel)]];

DLog(@"graphPanel.graphView: %@", graphPanel.graphView);
```

Works great until I try to access `graphPanel.graphView`:

```
2013-04-25 16:44:58.579 [15666:907] -[UIView graphView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e0c8320
2013-04-25 16:44:58.580 [15666:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView graphView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e0c8320'
```

and instance `0x1e0c8320` is the graphView's contentView that I created.

If I don't try to access the property, it will run w/out crashing.

Any ideals?

Comment: Silly question, did you `@synthesize graphView`?

Comment: @synthesize is no longer necessary with newer compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your init method.

Why are you doing the whole thing with `self = (HistogramGraphPanel *)contentView;`? `contentView` is not a graphView, but you set `self` to it with your cast. I think your code should work if you simply leave out that line.

In general, it is not a good idea to assign `self` to anything other than what is returned by `[super init]`, as you can probably see when the compiler gives you a warning/error without that cast.

Comment: If I don't assign the contentView to self, nothing appears. The code does run w/out crashing though. Do I `[self addsubView:]` instead?

Comment: Ok, I tried `[self addSubview]` and set the constraints and works like a charm. Thanks for pointing out that `self = contentView` was incorrect.